how to get specific object from array in firestore using reactjs
I can't get spefic object out of array that includes many objects. It's "messages" array that containes objects.
I used a method below but it returned nothing.
const [userId, setUserId] = useState();

const fetch = async () => {
const searcheQuery = query( collection(db,'chats'), where('id','==',userId));
 const querySnapshot = await getDocs(searcheQuery);
 querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => { console.log( doc.data() ) })

}

I also used 'array-contains' instead of '==' but results are the same.
 const searcheQuery = query( collection(db,'chats'), where('messages','array-contains',userId));



Can you please edit your question and show us the content of an object that exists inside the messages array?

You would need to pass the full object with array-contains for the query to work for example:
const messageObj = {
   date: "June 9 2024",
   id: "user-id"
}
const searchQuery = query( collection(db,'chats'), where('messages','array-contains',messageObj));

The == query is used for properties, so if you have a userId property inside your document, that query would work. To make the query easier because ofcourse you won't have the complete object, best thing is to add a subcollection with the messageObj as fields in that document.
You can check more here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

Do you know how to get the last object from array in firestore

If you need to make queries to find messages related to a specific user you can simply create a document for the user, with the user data such as username, email, etc, and then create a subcollection for the messages, then you won't need to make queries.
Also, storing user messages (assuming what you are storing is that) inside a single document is not a good practice, since it can scale up in size and reach the maximum size of a single document in firebase that is 1Mb.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
